# Error : NoSuchMethodError: Class '_AssertionError' has no instance getter 'code'

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

When I try to sign in with firebaseauth I keep getting a error saying

[Picture Of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKYKd.jpg)

I've been following a tutorial online about how to do this. But it still doesn't seem to work for me.

this is my code:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

bool isAuth = false;

FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

Future<bool> signUp({String email, String password}) async {
  try {
    User user = (await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)).user;
    return Future.value(true);
  } catch (e) {
    switch (e.code) {
      case "email-already-in-use":
        print("email-already-in-use");
    }
  }
}

Future<bool> signIn({String email, String password}) async {
  try {
    User user = (await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)).user;
    return Future.value(true);
  } catch (e) {
    switch (e.code) {
      case "user-not-found":
        print("user-not-found");
        break;
    }
  }
}

Future<bool> signOutUser() async {
  User user = await _auth.currentUser;
  if (user.providerData[1].providerId == "google.com") {
    await googleSignIn.signOut();
  }
  _auth.signOut();
  return Future.value(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your try catch block like this :

```
try {
    User user = (await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)).user;
    return Future.value(true);
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    switch (e.code) {
      case "email-already-in-use":
        print("email-already-in-use");
return null;
    }
  }
}
```

And

```
  try {
    User user = (await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)).user;
    return Future.value(true);
  }on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    switch (e.code) {
      case "user-not-found":
        print("user-not-found");
        break;
return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: did you  find it helpful ?

Comment: yes it was thank you @gladiator, but in the process I tried to make my code more efficient and now I'm getting a error with google sign in credentials 

Comment: You can upvote /accept if my answer , answered your question or you found it helpful